# How to share Angular services in promise chaining?

Tags: angular, typescript, promise

I'm working on Angular6 (typescript). I'm trying to chaining promise with the following code...

```
public start() {
    this.p1()
      .then(this.p2)
      .then(this.p3)
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }

  public p1(): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.httpService.sendHello().subscribe(response => {
        resolve();
      });
    });
  }

  public p2(): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.httpService.sendHello().subscribe(response => {
        resolve();
      });
    });
  }

  public p3(): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.httpService.sendHello().subscribe(response => {
        resolve();
      });
    });
  }
```

But an error appears "Cannot read property 'httpService' of undefined".

How should I do to share angular6 services in promise chaining ?

Thanks for helping,

Comment: Is `P1`, `P2` and `P3` are dependent on each other? I mean is it compulsion that `p1` execute first then `p2` and then `p3`.

Comment: If they are not dependent i will suggest you is the use `forkjoin` instead of chaining the promise.

Comment: @YashRami Yes, they are dependent on each other but thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript does not bind `this` when you don't use the arrow function.

Instead of `then(this.p2)` you can write `then(() => this.p2())`

```
public start() {
    this.p1()
      .then(() => this.p2())
      .then(() => this.p3())
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }

  public p1(): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.httpService.sendHello().subscribe(response => {
        resolve();
      });
    });
  }

  public p2(): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.httpService.sendHello().subscribe(response => {
        resolve();
      });
    });
  }

  public p3(): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.httpService.sendHello().subscribe(response => {
        resolve();
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You give it as an parameter to the function, like:

```
public start() {
    this.p1(this.httpService)
      .then(this.p2)
      .then(this.p3)
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }

  public p1(httpService: HttpService): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      httpService.sendHello().subscribe(response => {
        resolve();
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: And if you need it in the others too then: .then(()=>return this.p2(this.httpService))

Answer (score 1):

It's the `this` context. Convert them to arrow functions:

```
  public p1 = (): Promise<string> => { //...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RxJS` `forkjoin`here is the example

```
ngOnInit() {
  chainCall().subscribe(resp=> {
   console.log(resp);
  })
}

chainCall(): Observable<any[]> {
const response1 =  this.httpService.sendHello();
const response2 = this.httpService.sendHello();

return forkJoin([response1, response2]);
}
```